# How to Pattern Find with DateTime in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Hi I have some entries in sql server table that contains datetime2 values. When I run my select statement I get the following for the column UPDATEDATETIME:

```
UPDATEDATETIME
2021-02-11 23:14:05.727
2021-02-11 22:08:01.960
2021-02-10 19:28:10.263
2021-02-10 19:28:10.263
2021-02-10 19:28:10.263
2021-02-10 19:28:10.263
```

I wanted to only get the values from 2021-02-10 so I wrote the following query:

```
select * from dbo.logtable where UPDATEDATETIME like '2021-02-10%'
```

However this returns no values. I always assumed I can use this pattern matching to find datetimes since one can input datetime as string?
How can I get only the datetimes that fall in 2021-02-10?

Answer (score 1):

Use a range.

```
SELECT *
       FROM dbo.logtable
       WHERE updatedatetime >= '2021-02-10'
             AND updatedatetime < '2021-02-11';
```

Comment: I assume there is no such thing as regex for datetime?

Comment: This is the best method, as it works well with indexes. If you have a specific date in a variable, use `updatedatetime >= @date AND updatedatetime < DATEADD(day, 1, @date)` @dozie419 you really don't want to do that. Use [the date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#DateandTimeFunctions) for manipulating dates, they are the best.

Answer (score 0):

CASTing will help.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, UPDATEDATETIME DATETIME2(3));
INSERT INTO @tbl (UPDATEDATETIME) VALUES
('2021-02-11 23:14:05.727'),
('2021-02-11 22:08:01.960'),
('2021-02-10 19:28:10.263'),
('2021-02-10 19:28:10.263'),
('2021-02-10 19:28:10.263'),
('2021-02-10 19:28:10.263');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT * FROM @tbl
WHERE CAST(UPDATEDATETIME AS DATE) = '2021-02-10';
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------------------------+
| ID |     UPDATEDATETIME      |
+----+-------------------------+
|  3 | 2021-02-10 19:28:10.263 |
|  4 | 2021-02-10 19:28:10.263 |
|  5 | 2021-02-10 19:28:10.263 |
|  6 | 2021-02-10 19:28:10.263 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Comment: [Casting is sargeable but it might not be a good choice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

Comment: SMor, I concur. Wrote my answer without much thinking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.logtable
WHERE UPDATETIME >= '2021-02-10';
```